# How to check if a WebRTC video call is running on a remote machine?

Tags: web, webrtc, openwebrtc

I am very new to WebRTC protocols and hope someone can help me.I wrote a small test webapp that establishes a point to point video call using WebRTC. I load the app on the remote machine ( chrome browser ) and join the call using another machine (chrome browser too). My question is how to check if the call is active on the remote machine (Using remote debugging or any other way)?